# ExtJS Class constructor

Tags: extjs

I have a custom class created

```
Ext.define('MyFormPanel, {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    field1: null,
    field2: null

    constructor: function (config) {
            this.createFields();

            config.items.splice(0, 0, [
                    this.field1,
                    this.field2
            ]

            this.callParent([config]);
    }
});
```

However it will not add my fields to the form.   However, if I swap at the config.items.splice for

```
config.items[0] = this.field1;
config.items[1] = this.field2;
```

The form panel is created correctly.

My question is am I using the splice command incorrectly?   Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using splice correctly. It takes the elements to add as separate arguments, not an array

There are other problems:

- Name of class in missing a quote to close it
- Your call to `splice` is not closed, missing a `)`
- You have to make sure `items` is an array before you can call `splice` on it
- Config options have not been copied to `this` yet.

Try the following https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8ij

```
Ext.define('MyFormPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    field1: null,
    field2: null

    constructor: function (config) {
            this.createFields();
            config.items = config.items || [];
            config.items.splice(0, 0, config.field1, config.field2);
            this.callParent([config]);
    }
});
```

You should not override constructor. You should override `initComponent`

```
Ext.define('MyFormPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    field1: null,
    field2: null

    initComponent: function () {
            this.createFields();
            this.items = this.items || [];
            this.items.splice(0, 0, this.field1, this.field2);
            this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

From a readability perspective it makes it very hard to determine what your constructor is trying to do. Some improvements:

1. Move all the legwork to create fields into the initComponent as Juan recommends. This includes any dependencies on the fields in the current constructor to the parent initComponent.
2. You need to start invoking the super method with the special JavaScript reserved word "arguments" (as opposed to [config]) this will call another method with the argument signature which invoked the current method.
3. Pretty sure the only time you should need to override constructor instead of initComponent is when you are working from custom classes which don't extend off any component.
4. Why aren't you able to use the Panel#add() method to add your fields in initComponent? Splice feels hacky given the Ext API's allow you to add fields directly.

   ```
   Ext.define('MyFormPanel, {extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
   initComponent: function () {
     this.callParent(arguments);
     this.createFields();
   },
   createFields : function() {
        this.field1 = Ext.create('YourField1', {});
        this.add(this.field1);
        this.field2 = Ext.create('YourField2', {});
        this.add(this.field2);
   }});
   ```